# javascript not returning the value of a text input

Tags: php, javascript

I have this field on my screen which is a text input field, but when I try to access the value from JS it returns null

Below I've attached a screen shot where you can see that Chrome has the value stored (see left panel) and that JavaScript could not get the value (bottom panel) and the top half of the bottom panel you can see the html code.

Now I am also not sure if this will help but the fields are created dynamically using PHP, and the script is registered at the top of the html document. And there is only one of the fields with that name on my HTML Page

FULL HTML CODE

```
<body>
<link href="Objects.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="eFarmClicks.js"></script>
<div class="ContentPanel"><label class="HeadingLabel">ADD GROUP</label>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                 <td><label>GROUP NAME</label></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="edtGroupName"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>MAX ANIMALS</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="edtMaxAnimal"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>MAX MALE ANIMALS</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="edtMaxMAnimal"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>MAX FEMALE ANIMALS</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="edtMaxFAnimal"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmitAddGroup" value="Add Group" onclick="btnSubmitAddGroup_click()" ;="" onmousemove="mousemove(this)" onmouseout="mouseout(this)" style="background-color: green;">
</div>
</body>
```

Sorry about the way the code pasted. It was copied directly out of chrome.

[image: screen shot]

** edit **

My javascript code :

```
function btnSubmitAddGroup_click(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var groupname = document.getElementsByName('edtGroupName').item(0).value;
var max1 = document.getElementsByName('edtMaxAnimal').item(0).value;
var max2 = document.getElementsByName('edtMaxMAnimal').item(0).value;
var max3 = document.getElementsByName('edtMaxFAnimal').item(0).value;
alert(max1); // to test the value
};
```

** mouse move functions **

```
function mousemove(obj){
    if(document.getElementsByName(obj.name).item(0).style.backgroundColor!="blue")
    {document.getElementsByName(obj.name).item(0).style.backgroundColor="Green";};
};

function mouseout(obj){
    if(document.getElementsByName(obj.name).item(0).style.backgroundColor!="blue"){
        document.getElementsByName(obj.name).item(0).style.backgroundColor="transparent";
    };
};
```

****EDIT 4 OF TODAY**

(ALSO IN MY COMMENTS)

Guys, how will this impact my code? I just realized it might be relevant to mention that the edits are in an iframe. I realized this might be relevant when I checked this command document.getElementsByTagName('input')

Comment: Please format your code properly. I've formatted the code for you this time, but please take time to format it properly next time. For further help, see the [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: _'sorry about the way the code pasted. its copied directly out of chrome'_ Surely your keyboard works, though.

Comment: please check console.log(document.getElementByName('fieldname'))

Comment: Where is your JavaScript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest that you post code and error messages as text. Pictures scaled down to fit Stack Overflow layout are neither indexable nor reusable or readable.

Comment: Can you post your script too?

Comment: all my script codes are just sniplets of the js files, please let me know if you need any more sniplets

Comment: I'd love to know where this recent trend of ending functions with a semi-colon after the brace has come from. It appears to be becoming an actual problem these days (for readability reasons).

Comment: @GrantThomas I personally don't have an issue with it as far as readability goes - I add them in my examples out of habit, in my own projects as a matter of course I add the semi-colon to explicitly close the statement, why? because leaving them out tends to break a lot of code compression tools.

Comment: @Jacques I can't see an issue with the code you have provided - can you set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with just the code needed to replicate the error.

Comment: @Jacques - Do you generate the HTML items dynamically?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario yes i generate them all dynamically using php

Comment: guys how will this impact my code. I just realized it might be relevant to mention that the edits are in an I-Frame. I realized this might be relevant when i checked this command document.getElementsByTagName('input')

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/E3z4N/ make sure there is an actual value in the field.

Comment: i think that this might not work because of the fact that it is in an iframe. because when i run document.getElementsByTagName('input')  command in the chrome developer tools it doesnt show my textbox's it only shows all the content on the outside of the frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i found the problem, and i would like to thank [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330933/get-value-of-a-text-box-in-iframe-from-parent-window) and [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962633/get-textbox-within-a-form-of-an-iframe) for helping me get to the answer.

Okay so this was the actual problem:

- The iframe is created dynamically
- and the inputs were in the iframe (which i at first didnt feel the need to say in the original question)
- but after some further research and review i found that this was the cause of the problem

I assume its because the input was in the iframe which is a **seperate** document (and i still stand under correction). So the actual code to get the value was

```
document.getElementById('content').contentDocument.getElementsByName('edtGroupName').item(0).value
```

which could also be solved using the methods mentioned in the links.

for all beginners with js this is what the code does:

```
//this gets the i frame of the current page
document.getElementById('content')
// this is the document (or if you will, the page loaded in the iframe)
document.getElementById('content').contentDocument
//this gets my edit on my page of the frame
document.getElementById('content').contentDocument.getElementsByName('edtGroupName')
// and this simply gets the input value
document.getElementById('content').contentDocument.getElementsByName('edtGroupName').item(0).value
```