# is there any way to change urls is iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I want to show a page of my website within iframe in another page. 
I mean you can see helper.html while you are navigation main.php.
but I want to change some links in helper.html regarding to some conditions set in main.php.

The regular solution is to get content of helper.html and process it in main.php, then echo it.
But it is server side, I want this process to be client side.

Is that possible with JavaScript?

Comment: Can you change the source code of both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those files are on different domains but you have a full control of them, then use the following solution:

- In the main page call an iframe with GET parameters. For instance:

  ```
  <iframe src="foo.html?parameter=value" width="400" height="500"></iframe>
  ```
- In an iframe parse GET parameters using Javascript and show an appropriate content:

  ```
  // get the current URL
  var url = window.location.toString();
  //get the parameters
  url.match(/\?(.+)$/);
  var params = RegExp.$1;
  // split up the query string and store in an
  // associative array
  var params = params.split("&");
  var queryStringList = {};

  for(var i=0;i<params.length;i++)
  {
      var tmp = params[i].split("=");
      queryStringList[tmp[0]] = unescape(tmp[1]);
  }

  // print all querystring in key value pairs
  for(var i in queryStringList)
      document.write(i+" = "+queryStringList[i]+"<br/>");
  ```

  *Source:* http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2163

Comment: Code provided in this answer will print the Query String Collection, but how come this is the accepted answer when question talks about changing the link location inside the IFrame? Also see questioner comment on @Pwaddles answer.

Comment: @user961954 My answer explains how to pass data from the main page to an iframe. This data can be the information about urls that need to be replaced in an iframe. Then the iframe must have a script which parses the data and replaces needed urls.

Answer (score 2):

If your files are located at the same domain, you can use the `top.frames` property, ro refer to the `window` object of named frames:

Assume the top HTML to has such a structure:

```
<iframe name="main" /><iframe name="helper" />
```

Inside main:

```
top.frames["helper"].document.getElementById("linkID").href = "http://newlink.com";
```

If you're using AJAX, you can add the previously shown code in the callback handler. If `main.php` reloads on change, at the code within `<script>` tags.

Comment: The [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents pages from a different domain from comunicating with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('SomeIFrame'); 
myIframe.src = 'www.joobworld.com';
```

Comment: this probably changes the src of iframe not the href s within the iframe

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible if both frames are in same domain.
See sample function: in the help frame the `id` of link is assumed to be "link"

```
function ChangeLink()
{
    var Helpframe = document.getElementById("Helpframe");
    var innerDoc = Helpframe.contentDocument || Helpframe.contentWindow.document;
    var link = innerDoc.getElementById("link");
    link.href="http://www.google.com";
}
```

This solution is inspired from [Javascript - Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe)