# HTML5 - Cross Browser iframe postMessage - child to parent?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been following this tutorial - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2hOvZ7bwXU, which explains how to use postMessage to securely pass a message between iframe and parent - you basically end up with something like this - http://html5demos.com/postmessage2

My problem is that I need it to work the opposite way round (child to parent) and don't know how to target the parent window.

this is my receiver code (in the parent):

```
function handleMsg(e) {
    if(e.origin == "http://uc.dialogue.net") {
        let blah = e.data;
        alert(blah);    
    } else {
        alert("error");
    }
}
addEventListener("message", handleMsg, true);
```

and this is the sender function that is triggered by a simple form (in child):

```
   let text = document.querySelector('.srchInput').value;
   window.parent.postMessage(text, "http://uc.dialogue.net");
```

Should I be targeting the parent in a different way?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 148, accepted):

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    var key = e.message ? "message" : "data";
    var data = e[key];
    //run function//
},false);
```

Got it to work with the above in the parent page and the following in the child page -

```
parent.postMessage("loadMyOrders","*");  //  `*` on any domain
```

Code copied from [here](http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe).

Comment: Awesome! Note that in the eventer listener, `e.message == "loadMyOrders"`

Comment: Thanks for that. Though in Chrome I have `e.data == "loadMyOrders"`.

Comment: Sometimes you need to use window.opener.postMessage(); For example if child window had some redirects.

Comment: @iautomation how did you do it in Android WebView this is my problem as well... Your response would be appreciated.

Comment: Downvoted only because the code was taken verbaitum from [David Walsh's blog](http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe) without at least citing it as the source.

Comment: how to send message to child iframe? I want to get cookie form third party website to my iframe.

Comment: This works for sending messages from an iFrame to its parent—but on the parent page, I had to put the listener before the `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: For anyone reading this answer in the future, please do not include all the boilerplate junk, which is only needed for ie <= 8 . Just use `addEventListener` directly. http://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener Thank you :)

Comment: Agreeing with @AvindraGoolcharan's edit (and alternate answer below), the first three lines should be omitted in any website today.

Answer (score 36):

Unpacked the accepted answer using newer ecma262 spec, and dropping ie8 support:

```js
window.addEventListener('message', e => {
    const key = e.message ? 'message' : 'data';
    const data = e[key];

    // ...
},false);
```

Relevant documentation:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event#Examples

Answer (score 4):

This is a React version based on [Avindra Goolcharan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270302/avindra-goolcharan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37056813/2297433):

```
const MessageHandler = ({ allowedUrl, handleMessage }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleEvent = event => {
      const { message, data, origin } = event;
      if (origin === allowedUrl) {
        handleMessage(message || data);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('message', handleEvent, false);
    return function cleanup() {
      window.removeEventListener('message', handleEvent);
    };
  });

  return <React.Fragment />;
};
```

Where `allowedUrl` is the URL loaded within the `iframe` and `handleMessage` is a redux-connected function (or other form of state management) letting the rest of the app know about the received message.