# iframe to parent communication: parent.function vs postmessage

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, security

I am trying to send an object from an iframe to the parent site it is hosted on. I've found

[Html5 - Cross Browser Iframe postmessage - child to parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822907/html5-cross-browser-iframe-postmessage-child-to-parent)

and

[Calling a parent window function from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function)

I was able to get this to work in all browsers (postmessage didn't work in IE)

```
var data = {'iframedata': true, 'message':'object received from iframe'};
function sendDataToParent(){
    parent.receiveData(data);
}
```

All the posts I'm seeing say that parent.postmessage is the secure way to send data between windows in html5, so is calling a parent function and passing in a parameter as I am not secure?

Answer (score 0):

calling a function won't work if your iframe is in a different domain from the hosting page (parent).