# iframe opening full height in iOS - how to avoid that?

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe, embed

I use iframe to embed a widget from my site to the other sites.

This iframe contains several DIVs and one of them (`#statements`) is usually longer than the max height of iframe that I set up.

When I open it in a browser, it looks fine:
http://noduslabs.com/portfolio/hitech-companies/

However, when I hope it on an iPhone / iOS - the iframe height parameter is ignored and I see the full length of the page.

How do I avoid that?

Here's the code I currently use:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="660" src="http://infranodus.com/seogoogle/seoseo?background=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE**
In fact I don't want this iframe to be fixed height of 660, rather – that the user who embeds it could set up any height and that it would work on iOS (so 200 or 1000 - like they want).

Answer (score 0):

CSS height is typically preferable to explicit height declarations.   In this situation especially because you can also provide a  media query.

E.g.:

```
@media only screen and (max-height:800px){
  .myiframe{
    height:700px;
  }
}
```

Comment: so how do i avoid that?

Comment: hm, doesn't work. you sure it's `max-height(800px)` and not something like `max-height:800px`?

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe{
   height:660px;
}
```

Put that in your css file and it should be done.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want the height to be controllable from the `<iframe>` code directly?

Comment: Think you wind up using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822907/html5-cross-browser-iframe-postmessage-child-to-parent