# How to embed angular view to other application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have created 5 widgets in one html page and now I want to embed that page in another application; but I am bit confused on how to do it. 
Do I need to use iframe and call the page or any other way like that?

I have used iframe and embedded it in other applications but it is showing a menu bar and side bar as well. I only need to show widgets and I am using angularjs.

The application where I am embedding the dashboard page is a simple html page which doesn't have any script loaded in it.

Sample code which I have used:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8080/maxApp/#/dashboard" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make that URL as trusted by calling method trustAsResourceUrl.

**Code in JS:**

```
$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(yourURL)}}" src=" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Here is a sample [`Application`](http://plnkr.co/edit/TaypIkcdKcC4PnQIkzZ1?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan for your quick reply, with this i want to send login username and password. so should i send in url or some other way to send and access in parent function

Comment: Yes if you dont want it to be secured , you can pass in url otherwise follow the messaging mechanism to send the variables from iframe to parent

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan ones again. it really helped me will go through messaging mechanism tutorial or some sample code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822907/html5-cross-browser-iframe-postmessage-child-to-parent