# Respond with JS to an iframe file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, iframe, file-upload

I have an iframe that uploads a file to rails

I want to respond back with javascript. The format that comes in is `html`

I tried

```
<script>
   // JS code
</script>
```

But it loaded a new page and then executed the JS

Key is to upload a file asynchronously and then do more things on the page

Gem remotipart seems nice but i want to keep dependencies low

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for cross-origin communication. Refer to this post [Html5 - Cross Browser Iframe postmessage - child to parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822907/html5-cross-browser-iframe-postmessage-child-to-parent) to learn how to send child-to-parent page messages.