# Event Listener call back function not called

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, postmessage, dom-events

I'm trying to send a custom event from iFrame source to the parent. 
I've referred to [Html5 - Cross Browser Iframe postmessage - child to parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822907/html5-cross-browser-iframe-postmessage-child-to-parent) but I'm still not able to get the event to my parent.

Below is the code from iFrame source where I'm sending the event to the parent:

```
window.parent.postMessage('onWidgetDisplayed', '*');
```

In my parent, I have the angularJS controller file where I'm trying to listen to this event:

```
angular.module('common.controllers.vaultV2', [])
.controller('VaultV2Controller', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$sce', function($scope, $rootScope, $sce) {

        $scope.iframeUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://some-url");

        window.addEventListener('onWidgetDisplayed', onWidgetDisplayedEvent, false);

        function onWidgetDisplayedEvent() {
            alert("onWidgetDisplayed event received at parent");
        }

}]);
```

And here is the html file:

```
<div style="align: center">
    <iframe id="vault" ng-src="{{iframeUrl}}" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;  overflow: hidden" target="_parent"></iframe>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I don't see any errors in the browser console. 
Please help!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postMessage` sends a `message` event, not an `onWidgetDisplayed` event, so you'd want to hook the `message` event. If you need to send multiple types of messages, you can pass any arbitrary JavaScript value as the event data. You're already passing a string, so:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    if (/* check `e.origin` and make sure you're happy with it*/) {
        if (e.data === "onWidgetDisplayed") {
            onWidgetDisplayed.call(this, e);
        }
    }
}, false);
```