# Change the jQuery dialog title from child element

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have tried some method from web about changing the jQuery dialog title but I haven't succeed. Would someone help me how to do it. Thanks in advance

I have many existed popup page that using window.showModalDialog method to open. Now I need to change jQuery dialog box. I wanted to change the dialog box title depend on the popup page title. Now the popup page is in iframe and the iframe is inside the jQuery dialog. I add the function to change the title in popup page.

Here is my aspx page:

```
<div id="dialog">
   <iframe id="myIframe" src=""></iframe>
 </div>
 <button id="dialogBtn">Open Dialog</button>
```

The javascript to handle the dialog:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 600,
    open: function(ev, ui) {
    $('#myIframe').attr('src','http:Order/orderForm.aspx');
  }
});

$('#dialogBtn').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

There is the function to change the title on popup page  onload method:

```
 function changeDialogTitle() {
        var dialog = $('#dialog', parent.document);
        alert(dialog.length);
         $('#dialog', parent.document).dialog({ title: "New Dialog Title" });
}
```

I also tried this to reopen the dialog box but failed:

```
 $('#dialog', parent.document).dialog("option", "title", "New Title").dialog('open');
```

Comment: The question actually is. how to pass message to parent from iframe.
here is one answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822907/html5-cross-browser-iframe-postmessage-child-to-parent#answer-8849807

`eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    var key = e.message ? "message" : "data";
    var data = e[key];
    //run function//
},false);`  you need to (write code) to change title instead of `//return function`.

and here is docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('#dialog', parent.document).dialog({ title: "New Dialog Title" });
```

you can just run it in the parent, like:

```
function changeDialogTitle() {
    parent.window.$("#dialog").dialog({title: "New Dialog Title"});
}
```