# How to set transparent background of any page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have two jsp page(home.jsp, welcome.jsp). I want to show welcome.jsp on the top of home.jsp. I want to see the background as home.jsp and on the top of that welcome.jsp. But by default welcome.jsp page has white background. How to set transparent background color of whole jsp page (welcome.jsp).

Comment: Dude, you have more than 10k rep and almost 200 questions. Stop adding a signature to your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the element within the `iframe` or `frame` that has the background color set. "[Javascript - Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe)" covers accessing an element within an `iframe`.

Once you get the element, set the background color to `transparent`. There are multiple ways to do this:

```
element.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
element.setStyle('background-color', 'transparent'); // MooTools
element.css('background-color', 'transparent');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ // jQuery
```

References:

- [CSS background-color property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html)
- [jQuery and CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/)