# how to select tags within an iframe using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to select, and then modify, the HTML within an `iframe` I generate.  The iframe displays various media (images, pdfs, etc.).  To show different items, I initially create it using something like this:

```
$('#mydiv').html("<iframe id='myiframe' src='path/file.jpg'></iframe>");
```

and then, as needed, update its contents using something like this:

```
$('#myiframe').attr("src","path/newfile.jpg");
```

this produces HTML like this (as seen through Chrome's elements viewer):

```
<div id='mydiv'>
  <iframe id='myiframe' src='path/file.jpg'>
    #document
      <html>
        <body style="margin:0">
          <img style="-webkit-user-select:none" src="path/file.jpg">
        </body>
      </html>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

I want to select that dynamically generated `<img>` tag so that I can adjust its width.  But I can't figure out the jquery selector to do it.  Ideas?

Comment: is there a reason the jpg is being included in an iframe and not in an img/div with background-image?

Comment: why an `iframe` for image and not `img` ?

Comment: *The iframe displays various media (images, pdfs, etc.)*

Comment: blender has it.  sometimes the iframe shows an onsite or offsite PDF, for example.

Comment: see like question--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe

Comment: @mix this will only be possible with "onsite" aka same-domain files, "offsite" or cross-domain files aren't going to work due to same-origin restrictions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use jQuerys [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method. The docs even has an example titled "Change the background colour of links inside of an iframe."

> Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements,
>   including text and comment nodes.

Applied to your code:

```
var images = $('#myiframe').contents().find('img');
```

The real question is why do you need the iframe in the first place?

Comment: Correct answer, +1. And you where a few seconds faster then me!

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the contents of the iFrame first :

```
$("#myiframe").contents().find('img');
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is dynamically change an image in a container, you don't need the iframe.

You just need a an img tag on your own html that you can update it's src attribute.

```
$('#my-image')
    .attr('src', '/path/to/image')
    .attr('width', '100px')
    .attr('height', '100px');
```

unless you haven't told us a good reason to generate an iframe just for an image.
Playing with iframes like that can be painful specially when calling URLs from other domains