# works with document objsct using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html document with next structure

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
Some text
<iframe name="frame2" id="frame2">
#document
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Inner Text</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I select `<td>` tag from iframe2 using jQuery selectors and get it's inner text? I have no idea how can I select any tag from inner #document construction? Can some one chip in me?

Comment: Im not sure if it would work but i would say : $('body iframe table tr td')

Comment: You wont be able to unless the iframe content and your page are from the same domain.

Comment: From the parent: `$('#frame2').contents().find('td:first').text();` See: [`$.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to select tags within an iframe using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691662/how-to-select-tags-within-an-iframe-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firt you need the document of the iframe

```
var iframe_document = $("iframe").get(0).contentWindow.document;
```

than use jquery as normal

```
$("td",iframe_document)...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the td element with this jquery syntax:

```
$("#frame2").contents().find("td").text()
```

or using pure javascript:

```
var myIFrame = document.getElementById("frame2");
var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.table.tr.td.innerText;
```