# Loop through multiple elements from an Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, find

I have content loaded into a hidden iframe on a page and I'm wanting to loop through multiple elements on a page and get text using jquery.

Here is my current code:

```
$('#myiFrame').contents().find('div.air').each(function (index) {
       alert($(this).text());
     });
```

It only seems to find the one div with the class of 'air', although there is two divs on the page. How is my code wrong ?

Edit: I should say their are two 'div.air' on the page not under the same parent.

HTML it something like :

```
<section id="blah">
<div class="air"> text here </div>
</section>
<section id="blah2">
<div class="air"> text here </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Because you are finding only the div with class air? Just remove the `find` portion and see if it works.....

Comment: or you can remove the `.air` from the `find` argument, then you will be able to find all the `div`s.

Comment: Try [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `.find()`. `.find` is a recursive `.children`, so you may be transversing one extra elements level unintentionally.

Comment: There is two div.air on the page not under the same parent if you under stand what I mean . filter() seems to return nothing.

Comment: @AdamWare: you mean not under the same DOM element in the iframe, or not even within the same iframe or part of **your** page (not the hidden iframe's)?

Comment: @haylem Yeah, not under the same DOM element in the iFrame

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/q/1088544/850234 helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked out my own answer:

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('.air').each(function(){

    var foo = $(this).html();
    //do your Stuff here

});
```