# Getting an element from a different frame

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am desperately trying to get an element by its ID, which is located in another frame (NOT iframe). See following code to make things clear:

```
var elem = parent.frames['top'].document.getElementById('mydiv');
alert(elem); // returns null
```

.

```
<div id="mydiv">
...
</div>
```

If I alert `parent.frames['top'].document` I do get `[object]` returned. Am I missing something here?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe

Comment: alert won't show you the contents o f the object. use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: That is correct, because a DOM element is an object in JS and the default string representation of an object is `[object <[[Class]]>]`. It seems there is nothing wrong with what you are doing.

Comment: thanks for the answers. i just wanted to clarify that i get `null` returned when using getElementById. So I guess there is something wrong here, or did I missunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to use jQuery. You can achieve this as below

```
$("some selector", top.frames["frame_name"].document))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code `parent.frames['top']` returns a `Window` object. So you would have to modify your code as

```
var elem = parent.frames['top'].window.document.getElementById('mydiv');
```