# get text javascript + iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i have html code

site index.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <iframe id="html2" frameborder="0" src="html2.htm" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="height: 492px;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

site html2.htm

```
<html>
<body>
  <div><p id='123'>hello</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i using `document.getElementById('123')` in site index.html `return = null;`
how i can get it

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe
Also, id cannot start with a number and this will not work at all if the iframed page is in a different domain.

Comment: Greeting new user. Come with me in the backstreet. I'll show you a little trick : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @m59 You killed my urge to indent code. Thanks.

Comment: @MilchePatern hmm? I'm obsessive, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first access innerDoc of iframe by:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('html2');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

once you get the object, now you can access:

```
innerDoc.getElementById('divId');
```

For ID in html, you need to follow these rules:

ID should match:

```
[A-Za-z][-A-Za-z0-9_:.]*
```

1. Must Start with A-Z or a-z characters
2. May contains _(hyphen), :(colan) and .(dot)

but one should avoid `:` and `.` beacause jQuery selector conflict on these with class and filter.