# Get IFrameElement's nodes

Tags: html, iframe, dart

I'm having an IFrameElement on my page and I'd like to access it's nodes.

However, this sample:

```
frame.onLoad.listen((Event t) {
  print(frame.nodes.length);
});
```

returned 0;

That's obvious, because the IFrameElement doesn't have any direct nodes, but I had to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not allowed in Dart due to security concerns. You can only communicate with code run inside the IFrame using `postMessage()` or use dart-js-interop and code like shown here [Javascript - Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544)