# How can I bind click events to html tags inside tinymce editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce-4

I am creating a dialogue to enable inexperienced editors to correctly insert blockquotes into tinymce editor.
I want them to be able to click on the block quote and open it again in the dialogue for editing.
But how can I bind click events to the tags inside the editor? Here's the sort if thing I have tried (elm1 is the text editor, and I am using alert as poc)

```
        $('#elm1 blockquote').click(function () {
            var mh = $(this).html();
            alert(mh);
        })
```

Comment: So, did that work/not work? what is the problem?

Comment: I have discovered that, although the tinymce instance is declared as elm1, the editor - and contents - are actually in iframe. So the question is how do I bind to elments in this? http://screencast.com/t/vjTFjzj4

Answer (score 0):

You could also try registering your click event with the `$.on` method (doc [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/)).

```
$("#elm1 blockquote").on("click", function(e, el) {
  alert(el.html());
});
```

Also, since the context of your question did not include where and when your click handler is added, you might want to make sure that the event you have bound to your selector (`$('#elm1 blockquote'`) when it is available, such as wrapping it with `$(document).ready()`.

UPDATE (based on Iframe):

In jquery, it might look more like:

```
var blockquote $("#elm1_ifr").contents().find("blockquote");
// OR: var blockquote $("#elm1_ifr").contents().find("#tinymce");
$(blockquote).on('click', function(e, el) {  // Logic here... });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it didn't work. On further investigation, I can see that elm1 is actually empty 
http://screencast.com/t/B15ynRGX
The contents of editor are actually in an iframe created with javascript. So how would I bind to elements in this?...
http://screencast.com/t/vjTFjzj4
http://screencast.com/t/xTQI1eekQjml

Comment: Hmm. Since it is in a Iframe, you might need to be more specific in your JQuery selector. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1088569/1058612) post had some good insight on getting the contents of an iframe.

Comment: I am having trouble even selecting the iframe.  I have tried var iframe = $('iframe#elm1_ifr'); 
But the code doesn't run, and when I alert the contents, the object comes up as undefined.
Is it a problem that there is no value in the src attribute?
src="javascript:"""