# Access DOM from iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

I have inserted a HTML page into an `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="file:///C:/editor.html" width="1000" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Now I need to access to the DOM from the iframe and get an element by `id`.

This is my `editor.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Diagram</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script> 
    <!-- I use many resources -->
    <script> 
        function generatePNG (oViewer) { 
            var oImageOptions = { 
                includeDecoratorLayers: false, 
                replaceImageURL: true 
            }; 

            var d = new Date(); 
            var h = d.getHours(); 
            var m = d.getMinutes(); 
            var s = d.getSeconds(); 
            var sFileName = "diagram" + h.toString() + m.toString() + s.toString() + ".png"; 
            var sResultBlob = oViewer.generateImageBlob(function(sBlob) { 
                b = 64; 
                var reader = new window.FileReader(); 
                reader.readAsDataURL(sBlob); 
                reader.onloadend = function() { 
                    base64data = reader.result; 
                    var image = document.createElement('img'); 
                    image.setAttribute("id", "GraphImage"); 
                    image.src = base64data; 
                    document.body.appendChild(image); 
                } 
            }, "image/png", oImageOptions); 
            return sResult; 
        } 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body > 
    <div id="diagramContainer"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I need to access the DOM from the iframe, and get `image.src` from my `edtior.html`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.parent` or `window.top` to access the parent/primary frame window. Then you can get their elements with

`window.parent.document.getElementById("id")`

and so on.

So you can have in `iframe.html`:

```
<html><body>
<script>
     var getDiv = function(){
         return window.parent.document.getElementById("test");
     }
</script>
</body></html>
```

And a page containing it:

```
<html><body>
<div id="test"></div>
<iframe src="#####/iframe.html"></iframe>
</html></body>
```

Now calling `getDiv()` inside the iframe will fetch you the `div[id=test]` inside the parent frame.

If you want to do the opposite, i.e. access an element inside an iframe from outside the iframe, please read this answer:

[Javascript - Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe)

Comment: i'm getting null when i'm using this code :                                                                             <iframe name= "iframeEditor" id="ifrm" src="file:///C:/editor.html" width="1000" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script>
// reference to iframe with id 'ifrm'
var ifrm = document.getElementById('ifrm');
//ifrm.style.width = '400px'; // set width
console.log(window.parent.document.getElementById('GraphImage'));
</script>

Comment: I assumed you were trying to get an image from outside of the iframe inside the iframe.  Inside your iframe code (editor.html) you can access the DOM containing the `editor.html` iframe using `window.parent`. In the code you just pasted, your script tag is  not inside your editor.html code.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is  to create a javascript function that allow me to access the dom from iframe that contain my editor.html. i need an example please

Comment: I have updated the answer, giving an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is to access to **image.src** which is in my editor.html, and this using the iframe that contain my editor.html

Comment: i get error "cannot read property src of null" when i try with this code :var iframe = document.getElementById('ifrm');
// var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var innerDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
var a = innerDoc.getElementById("GraphImage").src;

Comment: most likely that code runs before the iframe document completes loading, meaning the item will not yet exist.

Comment: try `iframe.onload = function(){  /* put your code in here */ }`

Comment: <iframe name= "iframeEditor" id="ifrm" src="editor.html" width="1000" height="500" frameborder="0" onload="iframe()"></iframe>
<script>

iframe.onload = function(){ 

 var if1 = document.getElementById("ifrm");
 var fc = (if1.contentWindow || if1.contentDocument);
 var img1 = fc.document.getElementById("GraphImage");
 console.log(img1.src);
 }
</script>

Comment: i update the code but i have this erro with the onload function : Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: I have solved your original issue, this is now a completely seperate issue. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Comment: thank you i solved this problem, but i still have error cannot read src of null