# no found getElementById on element within an iframe

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

My current code works on elements outside of an iframe. How should I approach fetching elements within an iframe using getElementById?

```
<iframe src="about:blank" style="border-width: 0px; width: 100%; height: 280px;"></iframe>
```

[image]

Comment: Please refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1088569/6830901

Comment: not found id element.

Comment: Give your `iframe` an id, say, `myFrame`, and then use `document.getElementById('myFrame')`; You could also use `element` selector.

Comment: thank you
Will you give an example