# How to reveal hidden div on external page contained with in with iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to automatically reveal hidden div  when loading an external page?
Redirected page has a div (date picker)that is by default hidden under a link:

```
   <a class=" this-link" data-bind="fadeVisible: !isVisible(), click: change">Change</a>
```

On click  the div is visible and link disappears.

It is set similarly  to this example:

```
    < button>show and hide</button>
      <div id="mydiv"></ div >

#mydiv{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:red;
display:none;
    }

$('button').click(function(){
  $('#mydiv').toggle('slide',500)
   })
```

But i wish to have this immediately open (show ) on page load and, link to hide on click.

This 3th party tool is implemented to a page trough  a widget.
I tried adding this example  to a widget HTML code:

```
$(".change").show()
$('.change').css('display','block');
```

But its not working.

Can this be revealed trough JS or any other way?
Thank you.

Comment: Why not using onload event ?

Comment: When you mean "loading", do you mean referencing it in the titular iframe?  If so, that's an external site.  There are specific cross site scripting rules in place to prevent that sort of thing, for very good reasons.

Comment: nope. the onload event on frame

Comment: You're loading it through iframe ? A parent page can access frame elements : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe. OK. Just see it is external site. No way to do stuff in this case unless acting in external site

Answer (score 1):

You simply CANT

because of XSS policy in all browsers.