# Getting file upload error in dojo iframe - doc.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value undefined error

Tags: dojo

Getting file upload error in dojo iframe - doc.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value undefined error. File upload is failing intermittently when dojo(1.11.2 version) handleResponse() method is called before the response comes from the remote server .

Below is the error message i am getting

> Error: HTML Upload Error:Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at
>   Object._error
>   (/public/prod/dojo-1.11.2/dojox/form/FileUploader.js:18:56) at
>   Object.d (:244:264) at Object._error
>   (/public/prod/revolution-3.8.5/revit/form/FileUploader.js:12:300) at
>   Object.eval
>   (/public/prod/dojo-1.11.2/dojox/form/FileUploader.js:23:457) at
>   Object.error (:44:382) at :149:461 at g
>   (:163:21) at h (:162:331) at
>   h.Deferred.reject.errback (:164:304) at g
>   (:163:293) Message

I spent lot of hours in resolving this issue.But some how it is not getting resolved.Can anyone help me .

Comment: post your code here , how can we help you without it

Comment: Seems you are trying to get element within iframe. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1088569/9021949