# iFrame data fed into bcc of email

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is their a easy way to pull data from an iFrame and have it fed into the bcc of an email?

The iFrame contains a list of email addresses and user names. I do not need the user name, just the email addresses to be fed into a function for a button that will generate a email with all the email addresses in the bcc. I have the button function working but I just need to get the email addresses.

I hope this makes sense..

Here is my button function:

```
function firstButton() {

  var email = "mailto:?bcc=email@email.email" +
    "&subject=" + "Your QLIKSENSE Account has become dormant - FIRST NOTICE" +
    "&body=" + "This is a NOTICE informing you that your Qlik Sense account will be deleted due to inactivity. "

  window.location.href = email;

}

<iframe id="firstNoticeiFrame" src="https://URL"></iframe>
```

Comment: please share some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe