# How to access element attribute under iframe using jquery , which is in different domain

Tags: jquery

I need to access the form element attribute "action".
code:

```html
<iframe id="my_iframe" class="msg signin" scrolling="no" width="600" height="550" src="https://xxx">   
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>fgtyhnj</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <form action="https://cfvghg" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="BLOOD_ALEXA">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="https://dxfc">
  </form>
  </body>

  </html>
</iframe>
```

I have used the below line.
jquery:

```
$(#my_iframe).find("form").attr("action")
```

Comment: Not possible for security reasons

Comment: I also assume the HTML inside the iFrame tag is for illustration only? You cannot have a document inside the iframe tags like you have here

Comment: Lastly just access the page using Ajax, it supports CORS: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/e1hcsq9p/

Comment: hi @karthik, please take a look at this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1088569/4648586). seems your question relates to it. cheers!