# Can I get element inside #document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get an element inside #document?

[image]

Also, I can't find the way to use Jquery on chrome console.

Comment: Your element is inside an iframe, check here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe

Comment: i tried that before, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `iframe.contentDocument` or `iframe.contentWindow.document`:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("tidio-chat-iframe");
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var myDiv = iframeDocument.querySelector(".frame-content");
//Do something with myDiv
```

Comment: it works! really thank you!!

Comment: No problem @samkung, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.