# JavaScript works on chrome console but doesn't work in firefox or selenium code

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate the login to the following page using selenium:
https://services.cal-online.co.il/Card-Holders/SCREENS/AccountManagement/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fcard-holders%2fScreens%2fAccountManagement%2fHomePage.aspx

Trying to find the elements of username and password using both id, css selector and xpath didn't work.

```
self._web_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txt-login-username"]')
self._web_driver.find_element_by_id("txt-login-password")
self._web_driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#txt-login-username')
```

For all three I get NoSuchElement exception

I tried the following JS script: `document.getElementById('txt-login-username')`
when I run this script in selenium or in firefox it returns Null
but when I run it in chrome console I get a result I can use.
Is there any way to make it work from the python code or to run this on the chrome console itself and not from the python execute_script?

Comment: This is contained in an iframe. Chrome also doesn't find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe)

Comment: @VLAZ I get a security error

Answer (score 1):

To automate the login to the [page](https://services.cal-online.co.il/Card-Holders/SCREENS/AccountManagement/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fcard-holders%2fScreens%2fAccountManagement%2fHomePage.aspx) using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) as the the desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://services.cal-online.co.il/Card-Holders/SCREENS/AccountManagement/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fcard-holders%2fScreens%2fAccountManagement%2fHomePage.aspx")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='calconnectIframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='txt-login-username']"))).send_keys("ariel6653")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txt-login-password']").send_keys("ariel6653")
    ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: cal-online]

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

found a solution to the problem. the problem really was that the object is inside an iframe.
I tried to use the solution suggested in [Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe)

but got a security error. the solution is to switch frame the follwoing way:
`driver.switch_to.frame("iframe")`
and now you can use the normal find elment