# How to check from within a different-origin iframe if the iframe has clipboard-write permission?

Tags: javascript, iframe, clipboard

In an iframe that is from a **different origin** than its parent, I want to optionally display a 'copy' button if I detect that the iframe has clipboard-write permission. How do I check within the iframe if it has that permission?

I thought I could use Window.frameElement, get the iframe, and check its attributes to do so.
However, Window.frameElement gives null, because "the document into which it's embedded has a different origin" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement

Comment: you can not access an iframe in a different domain, not much you can do.

Comment: Related question: [Can text within an iframe be copied to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401384/can-text-within-an-iframe-be-copied-to-clipboard)

Comment: @epascarello, thank you. I'll see what I can manage.