# Accessing html elements from another page inside div

Tags: javascript, html, electron

So I'm pretty new to html/javascript but i'm working on a project where i'm loading a external html page inside a div, that when loaded looks like so:

```
<div class="content" id="content">
 <object type="text/html" data="./ProjectsHTML/radio_project.html">
   #document
 </object>
</div>
```

and inside the '#document' is the external html. This external html contains some titles that can be minimized and maximazed to hide/show their content.

I have a side-menu on the main html that displays all the titles (the titles were hard coded on the side-menu) and I want to **access the titles position inside the external html** so when the title is clicked on the side menu, the external html autoscrolls to the position of said title.

If it's usefull for the solution, I'm using Electron.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the pages are from the same domain, a similar question is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe).

However, if the page within the iframe is from a different domain, you won't be able to access individual elements - that's [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), and it is a security vulnerability.

There are a few options if you own both pages, even if they are on separate domains:

1. You could add [HTML links/bookmarks](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links_bookmarks.asp) to the page within the iframe and then reload the iframe when the user clicks the menu option on your host page. If would require a reload of the page within the iframe, but it could be used to get similar behavior.
2. You could [post messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to the iframe and handle "scroll requests" in the hosted page. You will want to be careful with validation of the source of those messages.

Comment: I wasn't using iframe but I guess it comes down to be the same thing as what I was doing. Then I can use the same solution mentioned. Thank you!!