# Get Content Of Current Time Element of Audio

Tags: javascript, dom, html5-video, html5-audio

I Want To Get Content of This Element With JavaScript

I tried to select pseudo element But I can't get content

1:
[image]

2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To select element which has no "class" keyword you could use [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```js
let el = document.querySelector('div[pseudo="-webkit-media-controls-time-display"]');
let content = el.innerHTML;

console.log(content);
```

```html
<body>
<div pseudo="test">0</div>
<div pseudo="-webkit-media-controls-time-display">1:23</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Doesn't Work,pro :(

Comment: It might be that player you trying to access is in the iframe. If this is the case, try looking into this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe