# Iframe navigation through link inside frame

Tags: javascript, html, web, iframe

Hey everybody I am looking to provide a feature that needs to navigate to different pages inside an iframe but not for the top level window only for itself. I have not found anything that can be used and I am looking to click on the links (  tags) through the iframe and not use the urls to redirect.

Comment: Is the iframe 3rd party? If yes, nothing you can do.

Comment: No it is not @epascarello

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe

Comment: So I just need to access the link through the contentDocument and then I can redirect just by clicking?

Comment: Assuming that is how it works....