# document.getElementById.value new failure

Tags: javascript, dom, document

I want to create an creditcard autofill for shopify pages.
My plan was to fill the cardnumber input field (for example) with document.getElementById('number').value = 12355444;

I've made two Observations:
1.) If I write it in the console nothing happens untill I do a right click in the specific input field and press inspect. After inspecting and executing in browser-console input-field will get filled. But why do I have to inspect the field first?

2.) If I execute the document.getElementById('number').value = 12355444; over my little Chrome-extension I'll get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
at :1:53

How do i get it worked?, **it seems like I cant access or it doesnt find the ID's of the input-form.**

If you want to try it out, take for example: https://newtonsupplyco.com/ cart sth and go untill payment.

Thank you

Comment: How are you creating a credit-card auto-fill? Where is the CC info coming from? That's the responsibility of a browser's own form auto-fill. Also, this is probably in huge violation of PCI requirements...

Comment: CC-Info just putting in as a text like in my example. Im mean by autofill doing it with document.getElementById('number').value. It works on other pages but on shopify I cant reach die ID's of the input-fields (its just a little project for myself, nothing for public)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the element is within an iframe. You cannot get to the element because that would be cross-site scripting. See [Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe) for more information.